# An estimate of a series with exponentials

Tags: laplace-transform

Provide an example of a sequence $(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty\subset(0,1)$ such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac23\right)^n\frac{p_n}ne^{-s3^{-n}(1-p_n)/2}=o(s^{-2}),\qquad s\to\infty.
$$
(From some geometric argument it's clear to me that such a sequence should exist, but I would need a concrete example.)

Comment: Huh? As $s \to 0$, the LHS goes to $\sum_n (\frac{2}{3})^n \frac{p_n}{n}$, which is not $0$....

Comment: $s$ should tend to infinity here, I'm sorry. Also, the little oh should have another exponent. I will re-edit the post. Thanks!!!

Comment: I think $p_n = \frac{1}{27^n}$ should work. The term $e^{-s3^{-n}(1-p_n)/2}$ is exponentially small unless $3^n \gg s$ in which case $(\frac{2}{3})^n\frac{p_n}{n} \le(\frac{2^{\log_3 s}}{3^{\log_3 s}})^{\log_3 s} \frac{1}{(\log_3 s)27^{\log_3 s}} \le \frac{1}{s^3}$.

Comment: @mathworker21 I managed to estimate only the $N$th remainder of the sum, $N=[\log_3s]$. Here go details. Fix $s>1$ and set $N=[\log_3s]$ (so $3^n\ge s$ if $n>N$). If $n>N$ we have
$$\left(\frac23\right)^n\frac{p_n}n=\frac{2^n}{3^n\cdot27^n\cdot n}=\frac1{(3^n)^{3-\log_32}\cdot3^n\cdot n}\le\frac1{s^{3-\log_32}\cdot3^n\cdot n}.$$ Thus
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\left(\frac23\right)^n\frac{p_n}ne^{-s3^{-n}(1-p_n)/2}\le\frac1{s^{3-\log_32}}\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac1{3^n\cdot n}<\frac C{s^{3-\log_32}}=o(s^{-2});$$ here $C=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{3^n\cdot n}$.